# Gallery keep images in in view at all times?

Tags: android, gallery

Is there anyway to keep images in the gallery set at all times?

Instead of reloading when off the screen or on image is swiped out of view by the user, is it a way to set it where the images never reload unless the application is closed?

EDIT: How to append this images to HorizontalScrollView?

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                /** The parent context */
                private Context myContext;public ImageAdapter() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }
                /** URL-Strings to some remote images. */

                public String[] myRemoteImages = {imageUrl,imageUrl2,imageUrl3,imageUrl4};






                /** Simple Constructor saving the 'parent' context. */
                public ImageAdapter(Context c) { this.myContext = c; }





                /** Returns the amount of images we have defined. */
                public int getCount() { 
                    return 10000;
                }

                /* Use the array-Positions as unique IDs */
                public Object getItem(int position) { 
                    return position; }
                public long getItemId(int position) { 
                    return position; 
                    }

                /** Returns a new ImageView to
                * be displayed, depending on
                * the position passed. */
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i = new ImageView(this.myContext);



                try {

                                URL aURL = new URL(myRemoteImages[position]);
                                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                                conn.setUseCaches(true);
                                conn.connect();
                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                                /* Buffered is always good for a performance plus. */
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                /* Decode url-data to a bitmap. */
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                                bis.close();
                                is.close();
                                Log.v(imageUrl, "Retrieving image");

                                /* Apply the Bitmap to the ImageView that will be returned. */
                                i.setImageBitmap(bm);

                        } catch (IOException e) {



                                Log.e("DEBUGTAG", "Remtoe Image Exception", e);





                /* Image should be scaled as width/height are set. */
                i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                /* Set the Width/Height of the ImageView. */
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
                    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(450, 300));
                return i;
                }
                else{
                    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 125));
                    return i;
                }
                        }
                return i;
                }




                /** Returns the size (0.0f to 1.0f) of the views
                * depending on the 'offset' to the center. */
                public float getScale(boolean focused, int offset) {
                /* Formula: 1 / (2 ^ offset) */
                return Math.max(0, 1.0f / (float)Math.pow(2, Math.abs(offset)));
                }
                }


((Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery))
                          .setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainMenu.this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of `AdapterView`s is precisely your "undesired behavior", to have as few items loaded in memory as possible. The real solution is to cache your images in disk so you do not have to retrieve them again. Unless you are already retrieving them from disk, in which case I would ask, why do you want this?

Edit:

Of course people in here know how to cache, perhaps you weren't asking the right questions? And yes, you definitely want to implement a cache. Anyway, caching `Bitmap`s:

```
private void putBitmapInDiskCache(Uri url, Bitmap avatar) {
    File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "thumbnails");
    File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+url.hashCode());
    try {
      cacheFile.createNewFile();
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
      avatar.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
      fos.flush();
      fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error when saving image to cache. ", e);
    }
  }
```

To read them it's similar:

```
  fis = new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
  Bitmap local = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```

Comment: I am loading the images from a URL. and what happens is when the images are off the screen and swipe back on it gives a little bit of lag. When i watched the debug i noticed they are being loaded all over again when off the screen. I just want a way where they wont keep loading. And ive been trying to get someone to show me how to cache on this website.. I suppose no one know how to because my questions never got answered. If you need ill post my code where i need to cache the images.

Comment: Yep, implement a cache, no way around it (well, no *good* way around it). See my edit.

Comment: Okay cool!!!!!! Thanks man! Where should i implement this in my code? Or how should i integrate it with code above? And what happens if the images change? Will the old images still be inside the cache?

Comment: Yes, this assumes that the images for a particular URL won't change, the images in the cache won't be deleted until the cache is cleared (or you delete them in your code). If this is not true then you could always reset the cache with every application restart or each day. As for where to put it, a quick solution is adding a Helper class which will keep the cache. See [this](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/loading-images-over-http-on-a-separate-thread-on-android/) for an example.

Comment: what should the cachefile be? and what shoud the Uri be in your code above?

Comment: Uri is just the image's URL, I use android's built in Uri class to keep track of them, any string would do. Each image uses its own file, that's why I create a folder in the cache directory (provided by android) and then just store the cached images there.

Comment: Could you comment it out? should anthing go here File cacheFile = new File(cacheDir, ""+url.hashCode());  in the ""?

Comment: a little confused im trying to integrate it with my code above.

Comment: Could you provide a little more guidiance on implementing your code above?

Answer (score 0):

How about using HorizontalScrollView instead? But be careful if you keep adding images to it then there might soon be out-of-memory exception.

Regards

Ziteng Chen

Comment: hmmm... Do you think maybe i could put the gallery inside the HorizontalScrollView and the images wont keep reloading after one time?? Hmmm....Probably not.

Comment: No I don't think a combo of Gallery and any other widget can disable the recycling mechanism. I mean you should use a HorizontalScrollView instead of Gallery, because the HorizontalScrollView is actually a FrameLayout supports horizontal scrolling and it will never recycle its subviews.

Comment: Check out y edit. How would i append the images to a HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: horizontalScrollView.addView(imageView)